# Writing gradle task to add a tag to git repo as a custom plugin

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle task where I can add a tag to my Bitbucket repository as below:

```
task createTag <<{
    def grgit = clone(dir: 'C:\\Repo1', uri: 'https://bitbucket.org/..')
    grgit.tag.add(name: 'tag-name', message: 'Some Message!')
    grgit.push(tags: true)
        }
```

Now, I want to move it to my Custom Plugin project. I am writing it as 
CreateTagPluginTask.groovy:

```
class CreateTagPlugin extends DefaultTask{
@TaskAction
def AddTag(){
    def grgit = clone(dir: 'C:\\Repo2', uri: 'https://bitbucket.org/smunjal12589/grgit_task')
    grgit.tag.add(name: 'tag-name', message: 'Some Message!')
    grgit.push(tags: true)
}
```

}

Plugin.groovy :

```
project.tasks.create("CreateTag",CreateTagPlugin.class)
```

When I execute this, I get error in Android studio project : Could not find method clone()

This doesn't work and doesn't recognize clone function. Any pointer how to get this.

Comment: Your original task is just a plain old task, your plugin task is of type GitClone?

Comment: No, I have done some editing. This is how it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get this resolved :

```
class CreateTagTask extends DefaultTask{
@TaskAction
def showLog(){
    println("Adding tag in the repo")
    def credentials = new Credentials("user","pass")
    def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: project.parent.projectDir,credentials)
    grgit.tag.add(name: "tagName", message: "tagMessage")
    grgit.push(tags: true)
}}
```